# Why is the address on stack 8 bytes farther?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, callstack, stack-frame

There is this mov instuction:

```
        0040064e 89 7d dc        MOV        dword ptr [RBP + local_2c],EDI
```

EDI stores argc from main function. I wanted to check its value by looking at rbp - 0x2c:

```
(gdb) x/x $rbp-0x2C
0x7ffffffee1c4: 0x00000000
```

As you can see, there is nothing there. The thing is - the argc value is 8 bytes farther:

```
(gdb) x/x $rbp-0x2C+0x8
0x7ffffffee1cc: 0x00000002
```

My question is - why does that happen?

Comment: Well, the machine code you've posted doesn't correspond to `MOV  dword ptr [RBP - 0x2c],EDI`. It corresponds to `MOV dword ptr [RBP - 0x24],EDI`. You can see this by looking at the `disp8` byte, which has the value `0xDC`, which is -0x24.

Comment: read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=vs-2019

Comment: I think it's 0x2c below the top of the stack frame (the return address), which is at RBP+8.

Comment: @SzabolcsDombi: the calling convention docs don't say anything about where a function should spill its register args inside its own stack frame.  And that's not even the right calling convention: with the first arg in EDI this is the x86-64 System V calling convention, used on everything *other than* Windows.  Anyway, the question is the naming scheme used by the OP's disassembler, not the calling convention.

Comment: You're asking why the disassembler prints `+ local_2c`, when the offset it uses in the instruction is `- 0x24`?